# Code to grep a pattern and print it as a column in the next lines until the pattern reappears

Tags: r, dataframe

---

I have been clueless and need help. I have a dataframe where in I want to look for a pattern starting with "-" hypon and print it as a column until the pattern appear again. Please see the example below:

input data frame:

```
--ABC
    1   John
    2   Jerry
    3   Tom
--DEF
    1   Harry
    2   Garry
    3   Glenn
    4   Vlad
--GHI
    1   Frank
    2   Harvey
    3   Adam
```

output data frame:

```
--ABC 1   John
--ABC 2   Jerry
--ABC 3   Tom
--DEF 1   Harry
--DEF 2   Garry
--DEF 3   Glenn
--DEF 4   Vlad
--GHI 1   Frank
--GHI 2   Harvey
--GHI 3   Adam
```

Data as `dput`

```
input <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("--ABC", "--DEF", "--GHI", "1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Adam", "Frank", "Garry", "Glenn", "Harry", "Harvey", "Jerry", "John", "Tom", "Vlad"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

The pattern that I am looking is starting with hypon followed by characters. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Can you share your input data using `dput` ? If your dataframe is called `input` do `dput(input)` as post the output here.

Comment: Ronak, please see the result below:                                                         
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("--ABC", "--DEF", "--GHI", "1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 9L, 8L, 
10L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Adam", 
"Frank", "Garry", "Glenn", "Harry", "Harvey", "Jerry", "John", 
"Tom", "Vlad"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

Comment: Please see the below is how my df looks like:                                                                                             V1     V2
1  --ABC       
2      1   John
3      2  Jerry
4      3    Tom
5  --DEF       
6      1  Harry
7      2  Garry
8      3  Glenn
9      4   Vlad
10 --GHI       
11     1  Frank
12     2 Harvey
13     3   Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new column using data from `V1` where `'--'` is present. We can replace the `NA`s with previous non-NA value using `fill` and remove rows which has `'--'` in `V1`.

```
library(dplyr)

input %>%
  mutate(V3 = replace(V1, !grepl('--[A-Z]+', V1), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(V3) %>%
  filter(!grepl('--[A-Z]+', V1))


#   V1     V2    V3
#1   1   John --ABC
#2   2  Jerry --ABC
#3   3    Tom --ABC
#4   1  Harry --DEF
#5   2  Garry --DEF
#6   3  Glenn --DEF
#7   4   Vlad --DEF
#8   1  Frank --GHI
#9   2 Harvey --GHI
#10  3   Adam --GHI
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. This works perfectly fine. Thanks mate!